# Update by row number in MySQL; foreach row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update every row of a table.

```
SET DELIMITER ;;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
SET i = 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 INTO n;
WHILE i < n DO
    UPDATE table1
        SET col1 = col1 + col2
        WHERE ROW_NUMBER = i;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;;
```

`ROW_NUMBER` above being something I find to find. I'm not sure how to find the row number of a tuple.

How do I update with a `WHERE` clause using a row number?

```
SET DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT
);;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    (5, 2),
    (2, 6),
    (3, 7);;

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|  5 |  2 |
|  2 |  6 |
|  3 |  7 |
+----+----+
```

Expected outcome would be:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|  7 |  2 |
|  8 |  6 |
| 10 |  7 |
+----+----+
```

Comment: Please edit your query and show the desired results.  What is `ROW_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increment all values of `col1` by `col2`, just do:

```
UPDATE table
    SET col1 = col1 + col2;
```

That's all.  SQL is a set-based language.  There is no reason to do an explicit loop for this type of operation.